# How to monitor a service in Linux via C++in QT?

Tags: c++, linux, service, qt-creator, qt5

I'm working on a small app to test waters in C++ using QT Creator on a Ubuntu box.

Here's the deal, I wanted to Start/Stop a certain service and as well monitor it's status in case it is started/stopped outside my app.

I got the first part covered which is starting/stopping the service using [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html).

While reading about the `QProcess` I came accross [**this**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#state) but unfortunately I can't make much sense of it to implement it.

I'd really appreciate some help here.

Regards,

Comment: I do not believe QProcess is what you want. I mean with QProcess you can spawn an application from your code and wait till that process ends have control of its stdin and stdout...

Answer (score 2):

Starting / Stopping services on a Linux box is best done via its service management interface and not via `QProcess`. Given that your project is new, I would not try to support Ubuntu proprietary service manager (Upstart) and instead build support for [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) that will replace it in the near future.

First you need to install systemd.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/420917/how-can-i-replace-upstart-with-systemd

Then try out this C++ library:

https://github.com/ilpianista/libsystemd-qt

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable info.
Since I'm on U13.10 which is the actual box I work with. Will it be good idea to go with systemd while there's uncertainty whether it will work with my system or not. BTW right now I'm not worried about future :)

The take-away right now from your answer is `upstart`.